# Compact 35mm film camera with decent 50mm-ish lens

Tags: film, compact-cameras, 35mm

I am looking for a non-wide angle compact 35mm film camera, preferably with aperture priority and exposure bias. The Fuji Klasse S seems like a good option but is still quite expensive, even second hand. Are there any alternatives?

Thanks, Jamie

Answer (score 1):

If you consider buying a used camera, you could look for a Leica cl/Minolta cle.
They have exchangeable lenses and are compatible to the rest of the Leica system (if you can afford the lenses).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a compact camera, but I have a EOS Rebel Ti with the typical 50mm 1.8 lens everyone has. Very cheap, very lightweight and very good, you can use it on aperture priority or full manual, it is a real EOS SLR. Only drawback is that it doesn't fit into a pocket.

I also have a point & shoot 35mm film camera which I never use.

Comment: I have a Nikon FE. It's also an SLR, but it **does** fit in a pocket when fitted with its 50/1.8. It has to be a big pocket though...